# Fundamental group of the complement of a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a smooth compact projective manifold of dimension $n \geq 2$ which is simply connected. Take $D \subset X$ be a smooth divisor which is isomorphic to the disjoint union of $s>1$ copies of the projective space $\mathbb{P}^{d-1}$.

> Is there an explicit nice expression for the fundamental group $\pi_1(X-D)$?

Intuitively I feel it should be some quotient of the free product of $s$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ but when I tried to prove it using the Van-Kampen theorem inductively I failed.

Comment: It depends on the normal bundle of the divisor.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you expand a bit on your answer?

Comment: If the normal bundle of a component $D_i$ of $D$ is trivial then $D_i$ contributes to the fundamental group, otherwise, it does not.